# struct inside of array not being updated

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a class with an array of structs that I want to modify in my program with the method `mark_value` but for some reason the structs are not being updated.

It has been some time since I used c++ so maybe I am missing something basic, sorry. My code looks like this:

```
class BingoTable {
private:
    int table_size = 5;
    std::vector<Number> numbers;

    BingoTable(std::vector<std::string> lines) {
       // populates the numbers vector.
    }

    void mark_value(int value) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < this->numbers.size(); ++i) {
            if (this->numbers[i].value == value) 
                this->numbers[i].marked = true;
        }
    }
```

for the mark_valuees I also tried this code:

```
 void mark_value(int value) {
    for(Number n: this->numbers) 
        if (n.value == value)
            n.marked = true
    }
```

Thanks to anyone taking some time here :D

## EDIT:

Sharing the whole code:

```
struct Number {
    int value;
    bool marked;
};

// constructor
BingoTable(std::vector<std::string> lines) {
        Number n;
        for (std::string line: lines) {
            std::string parsed;
            for (char s: line) {
                if ((s == ' ' || s == '\0') && parsed.size() > 0) {
                    n.value = std::stoi(parsed);
                    n.marked = false;
                    this->numbers.push_back(n);
                    parsed.clear();
                } else {
                    parsed.push_back(s);
                }
            }
            n.value = std::stoi(parsed);
            n.marked = false;
            this->numbers.push_back(n);
            parsed.clear();
        }
    };




 
//main
    std::vector<string> lines = ["1 7 5"]
    std::vector<int> values = [1, 5]
    for(int i: values)
    for(BingoTable table: tables) {
        table.mark_value(i);
        for (Number n: table.numbers)
            std::cout << n.marked;
        std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: `for(Number n: this->numbers) ` should be `for(Number& n: this->numbers) `. Right now you are creating copies of each element of the vector

Comment: I tried but array is not being updated between iterations, I am printing the whole array marked values after each iteration an the last updated value is printed as 1, but all the previous marked values are not updated. @UnholySheep

Comment: You will have to provide a proper [mre] then, the change in my last comment will fix the issue you mentioned

Comment: I added some more code, I think that will be enough for you to try the problem, let me know if you need more help

Comment: That's not "_the whole code_" and it's not a reproducible example. We can't compile that.

Comment: No, that is not a [mre], because it has syntax errors and doesn't contain all necessary code to compile it. Instead of coming up with something on the fly that you didn't even test yourself you should read the link and then try to create something *small* that reproduces the issue

Comment: Still: `for (std::string line: lines)` makes a copy of the line. `for(int i: values)` makes a copy of the value. `for (Number n: table.numbers)` makes a copy  of the number.

Comment: HI guys, sorry. I was in a rush. I just found my error. As @UnholySheep pointed I was using another for loop creating copies of my arrays. I will update this once I finish coding.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is not complete, but it seems that you are accessing a copy of your data, and not the original one every time.

Try:

```cpp
for(BingoTable &table: tables) {
```

and

```cpp
for (Number &n: table.numbers)
```

and

```cpp
BingoTable(std::vector<std::string> &lines) {
```

Comment: +1. Just to expand a little bit on the explanation, everywhere where an object is used in an explicit or implicit assignment (in the loops and where passed as argument), a copy will be created if we don't use reference via the `&` operator. The code modifies the copy and the original object remains unchanged.

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC or `&&` or `decltype(auto)`